# Why doesn't the Google Places JS API use an API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm working on a Google places implementation and was a bit astounded when I read about loading the [JS library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library) and using their [experimental places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search). The JS API does not require the API key (only to load the MAP which is mandatory). On the other hand, the new API uses the API key.

Is there any daily limitations with the Places JS API? Is it per IP? Any references? If I get correctly, I'd better stick with a client side JS to partly avoid Google quotas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Places Library of the Google Maps JavaScript API is only subject to request rate limiting per IP address.

The Google Places Web Service API is initially limited to 1,000 queries per day and 100,000 queries per day after billing has been enabled on the project. There currently is no cost for using the Web Service, even if billing is enabled, if you exceed your quota you will simply receive the response `"status": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"`.

You can request more than 100,000 queries per day by following the instructions on the [Requesting more quota](https://developers.google.com/places/uplift) page of the documentation.

Comment: :That means that if I use the Places library in my website,the limit will be only to the IP of the user that uses my site?I.e that it will be almost impossible to reach the limits.Is this correct?thanks